# Multidimensional array sum in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array is :

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => DCL
            [Duration] => 18
            [Min] => 31
            [CostD] => 4
            [CostD1] => 4
        )

   [1] => Array
       (
          [Name] => Ins
          [Duration] => 51
          [Min] => 1
          [CostD] => 0.00
          [CostD1] => 0.04
       )


[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => N2P
        [Duration] => 51
        [Min] => 1
        [CostD] => 0.04
        [CostD1] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Name] => N2P
        [Duration] => 17
        [Min] => 2
        [CostD] => 13.61
        [CostD1] => 13
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Name] => DCL
        [Duration] => 10
        [Min] => 0
        [CostD] => 5
        [CostD1] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Ins
        [Duration] => 300
        [Min] => 5
        [CostD] => 0.44
        [CostD1] => 0.00
    )


[6] => Array
    (
        [Name] => RNB
        [Duration] => 341
        [Min] => 0
        [CostD] => 0.44
        [CostD1] => 0.00
    )

 [7] => Array
    (
        [Name] => DCL
        [Duration] => 20
        [Min] => 0
        [CostD] => 12.8
        [CostD1] => 12
    )
```

)

i want new array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [Name] => DCL
          [Duration] => 48
          [Min] => 31
          [CostD] => 21.8
          [CostD1] => 21
       )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [Name] => Ins
          [Duration] => 351
          [Min] => 1
          [CostD] => 0.00
          [CostD1] => 0.04
      )


[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => N2P
        [Duration] => 68
        [Min] => 3
        [CostD] => 13.16
        [CostD1] => 13
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [Name] => RNB
        [Duration] => 341
        [Min] => 0
        [CostD] => 0.44
        [CostD1] => 0.00
    )
```

)

Please help.Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you try anything?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yes but failed always .

Comment: @TahajjatTuhin i'v just posted solution, is it acceptable? If yes, please mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $sumArray = array();
        foreach ($data as $k => $row) {
            if (!isset($sumArray[$row['Name']])) {
                $sumArray[$row['Name']] = $row;
            } else {
                foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
                    if (is_numeric($v)) {
                        $sumArray[$row['Name']][$k]+=$v;
                    } else {
                       // decide here what to do if value is a string
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $result = array_values($sumArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $r){
            $values[$r['Name']]['Name']      = $r['Name'];
            $values[$r['Name']]['Duration'] += $r['Duration'];
            $values[$r['Name']]['Min']      += $r['Min'];
            $values[$r['Name']]['CostD']    += $r['CostD'];
            $values[$r['Name']]['CostD1']   += $r['CostD1'];
    }
    print_r(array_values($values));
```